# Collections Navigate and update, (no new collections) How to do with Java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a aList and a bList, both have one field common which is my refernece to match two lists.
Once the two lists reference matches i want to update the bList Objects with aList. 
Conventional approach is as below, How can i achieve same in java 8 ?

```
    // How to save below piece of two iterations (along with compare* and update*) 
    // using java 8 ?
    // Stream filter will return new Collection but not update same (bList)

    for (A a : aList)
    { 
       for(B b: bList )
       {

         // compare*
         if(a.getStrObj.equalsIgnoreCase(b.getStrObj))
         {
            // update*
            // assume aObjs is initialized
            b.getAObjs().add(a);
         }

        }
    } 

     // Reference for Objects declaration
       List<A> aList;

        class A {

          String strObj;

          public String getStrObj()
          { return strObj; }

        }

        List<B> bList;

        class B {

          String strObj;

          List<A> aObjs;

          public getStrObj()
          { return strObj; }

          public setAObjs(List<A> aObjs)
          { this.aObjs= aObjs; }

          public getAObjs()
          { return this.aObjs;}

        }
```

Comment: So you code does not work now? What's the question? Also please supply the compilable code. Currently it's full of compilation errors. Do you really compare strings with == ?

Comment: `b.setAObjs(a);` takes a List but you set it with a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop is not the best way to do it, even before Java 8 (unless you can prove that the lists will always be rather small). You should use a temporary `Map` with a fast lookup for one of the lists to avoid to perform `m×n` operations (string comparisons).

One way to do that with Java 8 is

```
Map<String, List<A>> m=aList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getStrObj));
bList.forEach(b -> b.getAObjs()
                    .addAll(m.getOrDefault(b.getStrObj(), Collections.emptyList())));
```

Here we are performing `m+n` operations rather than `m×n` operations which scales much better with growing list sizes.

You can create an equivalent implementation with pre Java 8 constructs, i.e. two independent loops rather than two nested loops and the resulting code isn’t necessarily worse than the above Java 8 code.

Still, the above code might introduce to you some of the most important features (a method reference, a lambda expression, a stream collect operation and one of the new `default` operations of the `Map` interface), so you know where to start next time when solving a similar problem.